# I can't move application which program in Java

Tags: java, widget

[image: error]

I have an error that I can't move or edit the application.

What is my error I think it is running but I'm having a problem.

the application which is located the left of top are shown.

Comment: Is this a question? Are you sure?

Comment: Please share more informations, like what you're trying to do and what error you're getting.

Comment: yes i'm sure @PradeepSimha . Are you kidding me ?

Comment: I'm the new this website ,so i didn't put the image .

Comment: @CWOmer, your question is very unclear

Comment: Where is unclear @PradeepSimha ?

Comment: I suggest you look at using the GUI designer in Eclipse.  You might find it will save you allot of time. ;)

Comment: i don't know to use clearly Eclipse ,so i have an error but you might be helpful..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you did set `undecorated(true)`, that's why you can not move the application.

This method will remove the standard actions like, minimize, resize and close. Even so, it will disable the drag and drop bar on top of each Frame. 
Just comment out this line and it will be moveable again

Hope this is what you are searching for

Comment: +1 I guess the grey square in the top right is the OP's application.  The moral of the story is; if your program is doing something strange you probably added code which you didn't know what it did. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot , people who looks like can help to other people, but somebody kidding the new user or programmer. Thanks for everything. Sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

> i can't move or edit the application.

All I can see is a warning that you have a Serializable class which doesn't define a serialVersionUID.  Eclipse should have a quick fix for this, if you care which I suspect you shouldn't.  You can turn off the warning.

Comment: How can i turn off the warning ?

Comment: I haven't use eclipse for many years but in most IDEs you just right click the warning and chose an option to turn it off.

Comment: or window -> preferences -> java -> java compiler -> errors and warnings. Eclipse is a pretty complicated tool to use properly, it pays off to make the effort to Google for articles on it to learn its nuts and bolts if you don't want to eat through the manual.

Comment: thanks a lot. i will try to do. I'm the new user on Java . Therefore, there could be errors .

Comment: Learning how to ask question on the forum is very tricky for new comers I fear. ;)

Comment: you are right. I will try to do that how question i ask.